# Can a Picture Box be added to a List Box WinForms

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox and I'm trying to add a number of picture boxes to it. I have a for loop that should add a picture into the listbox every time it goes into the loop. In my for loop the count can be any number however in this case the count is 5. However it never adds a picture all it adds is a blank clickable space. What I want it to look like eventually is something like this. [image]

My code is as follows

```
                For i As Integer = 1 To level3Cat.Count

                    Dim picture As PictureBox = New PictureBox With
                        {.Name = "pictureBox" & i,
                        .Size = New Size(316, 320),
                        .Location = New Point(i * 316, 1),
                        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                         .BackgroundImage = My.Resources.XButton}

                    ListBoxTemplates.Items.Add(picture)
                Next
```

Comment: And what does not work with your code? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: I have edited my question but I will explain here as well. What happens is it adds like a blank clickable item to my list box every time I go into the for loop and nothing else

Comment: Take a look at how to add picturebox to list view: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?669922-RESOLVED-Listview-choice-display-picturebox

Comment: Why do you think you need a `ListBox` at all? What is it supposed to do for you? My guess is that you should just use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`.